# Magento 2 how to create link_title column for the table catalog_product_link

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, simple-product, link

How to create column called `link_title`  to the `catalog_product_link` table 
& what are the steps, need to be followed to set the value to the respected column

[image]

Did small prototype as followed here but unable to save data.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$sourceMaterial='24-MB01';
$productLink = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface')
    ->setSku($sourceMaterial)
    ->setLinkedProductSku('24-MB06')
    ->setLinkTitle("helloworld")
    ->setLinkType('required');
$linkData[] = $productLink;
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->get($sourceMaterial);
if($product) {
    $product->setProductLinks($linkData)->save();
}
?>
```

The recorded data is saving without  `link_title` value not saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For create link_title column

Create **InstallSchema.php** :

> app/code/RH/Helloworld/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php
namespace RH\Helloworld\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface {

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        $eavTable = $installer->getTable('catalog_product_link');

        $columns = [
            'link_title' => [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' => 'Link Title',
            ],

        ];

        $connection = $installer->getConnection();
        foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
            $connection->addColumn($eavTable, $name, $definition);
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

### For save record in custom column :

Inject this below code in your construct :

```
    protected $productFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
        ...
    ) {
        ....
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        ....
    }
```

And then, use this below code in your function :

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create()->load(45); //Set your product id here
$link = $product->getLinkInstance()->load(1); //Set your link id here
$link->setLinkTitle('test'); //Set your link title value here
$link->save();
```

Don't forget to execute this below command :

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
```

Hope, It will helpful for you.

---

**Output :**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @rohan let me check and get back to you.

Comment: Hi, @rohab Here we would like to use set title concept by the custom import, In this scenario how do we get link_id can u advise?

Comment: You can get link id based on product id and then, you need to set based on your requirement.

Comment: Can u advise me based on this concept https://codeshare.io/G7jEwr here how do i set?

Comment: Why you run script from root path. You can also create controller and set code which I posted. It's working. I tested in my instance.

Comment: First, try with set static value as like I set. If it'll working then, mark as accepted. So, It will helpful for others.

Comment: Hi @rohan There is an issue i.e if the product save at backend that link_title is removing can u please suggest? I am able to set from frontend but when i save the product_id 45 the link title is gone  can u try from your end once

Comment: Okay. will try and update you soon.

Comment: If you run script from root folder then, please set area code adminhtml.

Comment: Could you please help me on this I have provided details here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300940/magento-2-how-to-save-my-custom-link-titles-from-magento-2-admin-end