# Magento 2 how to save my custom link titles from Magento 2 admin end

Tags: magento2, custom, catalog, link

We have created a custom link type products like `related` at admin end & we created custom `link_title` for the table `catalog_product_link` to save the custom titles.

By custom import, we are able to save the custom titles in the `catalog_product_link` table.
But the problem is if the admin user saves the product at the admin end the respected link type records are being deleted and recreated by the default behavior of Magento2.

There is a file **vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Link/SaveHandler.php:: execute()** which has been triggering after saving product and which is responsible for saving links.

How to overcome this issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add code?

Comment: @Nagaraju please help me my question "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300938/magento2-3-3-getting-error-on-console-not-loaded-js"

Comment: vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Link/SaveHandler.php